# Delete an unanswered question if I no longer need the answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, unanswered-questions

I wrote the following question: [Can Ride be used to Push a mount/animal companion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192887/can-ride-be-used-to-push-a-mount-animal-companion) containing multiple questions. I was asked to separate them out, so I did. Once I separated out the question [When pushing an animal, how long will it perform the trick it doesn't know?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192910/when-pushing-an-animal-how-long-will-it-perform-the-trick-it-doesnt-know/192912#192912), the separate question was answered. With that answer, I realized I did not need an answer to the original question. Since the original question is unanswered, is it OK for me to delete it? The answered question kind of makes the original question irrelevant for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don’t think anyone’s going to undelete your question if you delete it. Even if they did, it’s not like you’d be “in trouble” for it or anything. You could even, if you wanted nothing more to do with it but folks insisted on keeping it undeleted, ask to have the question dissociated from your account. But I really doubt this is going to come to that. Yes, it is “OK” for you to delete it.

On the other hand, it’s also a perfectly reasonable question. Maybe you no longer feel like you need the answer, but it could still be useful to someone. And even if the demands on your Handle Animal checks are less than you thought, if there’s an answer that’s cheap enough you still might end up using it. So at least if it were me, I wouldn’t choose to delete it.

But if you do, I don’t think anyone’s going to cry foul.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the advice :) I'll leave it open then in case it helps someone else.

Comment: If you think the answer to your first question also answered your second question, the ideal might be to close your second question as a duplicate of the first.

Comment: @ObliviousSage While certainly sage (har.) advice in general, here these two questions certainly aren’t duplicates. Rather, it’s more that the original question had two parts, but the second part only mattered (to InterstellarProbe) if the answer to the first was “No.” Since it was “Yes,” IP no longer really needs the answer to the second—but the second is still a separate and potentially-interesting question.

Comment: Ah, then in that case leaving it open is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 4):

### Don't delete it - answer it

You asked a question. That's good. You now know the answer. That's better. Armed with this knowledge, you now answer your original question so it is an ongoing benefit to others. That's best.

Comment: Down to the point, we are a resource for everyone not just a help desk.

Comment: This doesn’t really apply to this situation. The answer IntestellarProbe got meant that this question was no longer a real problem they faced, but the answer they got didn’t _answer_ this question, it just _obviated it_ (for IntestellarProbe). Good advice, in general, but not here.